# Match internal domain links only using regex

Tags: python, regex

I've been working on this regex expression for quite a while without much luck.

Basically, I'm hoping to solve the following problems:

```
Match:

http://ourwebsite.com/index.html <-- match index.html only
ourwebsite.com/index.html <-- match index.html only
ourwebsite.com/about.html#something <-- match about.html only
index.html <-- match index.html
/about.html <-- match about.html (do not match /, only about.html)
/index <-- match index
/index/ <-- match index/
index/ <-- match index/
/about <-- match about
/about/ <-- match about/
about/ <-- match about/
/about/us/ <-- match about/us/

No match:

someotherwebsite.com/index.html <-- do not match anything
someotherwebsite.com/index <-- do not match anything
```

In other words, only match internal website links, but eliminate the starting `/`.

Here's what I've constructed thus far:

```
^(?:(?:https?):\/\/|\b)http\:\/\/ourwebsite\.com.*|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-z]{3,})
```

This regex solves most of what I'm trying to do, however, still matches `someotherwebsite.com`.

I'm guessing my regex isn't completely optimal either.. Is there an easier way to do this?

I'm using Python for this by the way. If there's any libraries that could do this, I'm all ears.

Comment: Do the ones in red also contain ourwebsite.com text?

As in about/ has the text at the beginning or not?

Comment: I tried pasting it as it was but SO kept insisting on making it a code block which might be the cause of the red color. The red color has no matter in this case. Anyhow, the ones below `ourwebsite.com` such as `about/` are all internal links and they should match just fine. Basically, as long as either: A) They are internal links like (about/ or about.html), they should match, OR B) If they are internal links like ourwebsite.com/link.html, they should also match

Comment: Basically just skip any links that aren't related to the website. Like, http://facebook.com/my-profile

Comment: could you split it into two- one containing the mainsite and the other containing rest of the stuff and if mainsite is a match, it should be fine else do nothing with the remaining values. Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: also, the red color is indicating quotes. You can use it as \' to not mark it as a quote and there would be no red color.

Comment: That was my original approach to it. In the regex that I constructed above you can see that I'm trying to match the website, then I have an alternation between website matches and direct link matches. But the direct link matches still matches `someotherwebsite.com`. I guess the only way to solve that is to check for `.html`/`.php`, etc.. Right?

Comment: Updated my answer with a python library solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I assume is the case-

the URL is of the form `yourwebsite.com/blah` and all the pages contain at least `yourwebsite.com` or `www.yourwebiste.com`as text

so, I created a dict of 3 samples, depending on if it contains https, www or without www-

```
d = ["https://www.example.com/index.html", "www.example.com/index.html", "example.com/index.html"]
```

Next, since we always search for only the matches, we split it with `example.com` since that remains constant anyhow.

for showing all the elements of dict above, we have

```
import re
for i in d:
    parts = re.split(r'example.com/', i)
    print(parts)
```

which gives me output as follows-

> ['https://www.', 'index.html']
>   ['www.', 'index.html']
>   ['', 'index.html']

You can always select the second one by using `parts[1]` for your processing.

Comment: Is it always safe to assume that parts[1] will contain the link? What if `["https://example.com/about-us/more-info.html"]` was in the dict? Or how would this filter out `["https://facebook.com/about-us/"]`?

Comment: it does return `about-us/more-info.html`

Comment: In that case, it looks like a nice and clean approach. 1+ for sure. Can you think of any edge cases where this would fail?

Comment: The thing is, if you are reading a lot of text and finding this in between, you have to make sure you are only working with URL for this. Otherwise, it'll split the whole text based on this approach. Otherwise, I don't think this would fail.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Added note- if you have split the read text on basis of whitespace characters, this appproach will work without any issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

### First Proposal

This regex will give you the relative urls from the urls you've provided, but it doesn't give you the domain distinction.

> ^(?:http://)?(?:(?:www.)?ourwebsite.com)?(?:/)?([a-z0-9/.]+)

**Tests:**

https://regex101.com/r/Oi2jh8/1

**Explanation:**

- Optional `http://` prefix as a non capturing group
- Optional `www.` prefix as a non capturing group
- Optional `ourwebsite.com` domain as a non capturing group
- Optional `/` domain path separator as a non capturing group
- capture the path which contain the characters `[a-z0-9/.]` (not `#` or `?`, will end there, you can extend the list with `_` or `-` etc.)

---

### Second proposal

> ^(?:http://)?((?:www.)?[.a-z0-9-_]+/)?([a-z0-9/.]+)

Which also matches the domain as a capturing group, if a domain exists, you will get the matched group length as 2, then you can eliminate if matches[0] doesn't match `ourwebsite.com`:

**Tests**

https://regex101.com/r/Oi2jh8/3

---

**Note**, If you want to parse the urls without using regex on python:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.cwi.nl:80', path='/%7Eguido/Python.html',
        params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Taken from: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into the regex explanations in detail tomorrow. I think the `urlparse` library is the way to go here. Seems to be the cleanest way by far.

Comment: Yep, I also think so.